# Comparing values from a string in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, comparison, multiple-value

I'm having some trouble comparing values found in VARCHAR fields.

I have a table with products and each product has volume. I store the volume in a VARCHAR field and it's usually a number (30, 40, 200..) but there are products that have multiple volumes and their data is stored separated by semicolons, like so 30;60;80.

I know that storing multiple volumes like that is not recommended but I have to work with it like it is.

I'm trying to implement a search by volume function for the products. I want to also display the products that have a bigger or equal volume than the one searched. 
This is not a problem with the products that have a single volume, but it is a problem with the multiple volume products.

Maybe an example will make things clearer: Let's say I have a product with this in it's volume field: 30;40;70;80. 
If someone searched for a volume, lets say 50, I want that product to be displayed.

To do this I was thinking of writing my own custom MySQL function (I've never this before) but maybe someone can offer a different solution.

I apologize for my poor English but I hope I made my question clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Performance is going to be terrible on this query if the table is very large since you won't be able to take advantage of any indexes on the field.

Comment: Are the volumes always stored in increasing order from left to right?

Comment: JohnFx, we're going to use cache so hopefully that will improve performance.

Mark Byers, I'm not sure to be honest, I'll have to check that with someone tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to compare with the largest value. Are the volumes always stored in increasing order from left to right? If so then compare with the value after the last semicolon if one is present. You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to select the last value.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(volume, ';', -1) AS UNSIGNED) >= 50
```

Comment: Your answer looks feasible, thanks a lot.
About the ordering of the volumes, I'm not exactly sure right now but I suspect they respect an ascending order.

Comment: >Are the volumes always stored in increasing order from left to right?
Yes they are.